# How the current point and reversepath work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I am a little bit confused with the behavior of `\reversepath`. In my investigation, it seems `\reversepath` will reverse all preceding  paths. For example,

```
\pathA
\pathB
\reversepath
```

both path A and B will be reversed,

```
\pathA
\pathB
\reversepath
\pathC
\reversepath
```

only path C will be reversed and reversing on A and B is neutralized.

For an illustration purpose, let me take a trivial example in which I want to draw house-like closed curves `\Outer` and `\Inner` as follows.

### Outer

```
\psline(2,2)(3,4)(4,1)(4,-3)
\reversepath % becomes (4,-3)(4,1)(3,4)(2,2)
\scale{-1 1}
\psline(2,2)(3,4)(4,1)(4,-3) % becomes (-2,2)(-3,4)(-4,1)(-4,-3)
\closepath % line from (-4,-3) to (4,-3) CCW
```

[image]

### Inner

```
\moveto(1,0)
\psline(1,0)(2,1)(3,0)(3,-2)
\reversepath % becomes (3,-2)(3,0)(2,1)(1,0)
\scale{-1 1}
\psline(1,0)(2,1)(3,0)(3,-2) % becomes (-1,0)(-2,1)(-3,0)(-3,-2)
\closepath % line from (-3,-2) to (3,-2) CCW
```

[image]

### Combination

```
\psline(2,2)(3,4)(4,1)(4,-3)
\reversepath % becomes (4,-3)(4,1)(3,4)(2,2)
\scale{-1 1}
\psline(2,2)(3,4)(4,1)(4,-3) % becomes (-2,2)(-3,4)(-4,1)(-4,-3)
\closepath % line from (-4,-3) to (4,-3) CCW

\scale{-1 1} % neutralize the previous scale

\moveto(1,0)
\psline(1,0)(2,1)(3,0)(3,-2)
\reversepath % becomes (3,-2)(3,0)(2,1)(1,0)
\scale{-1 1}
\psline(1,0)(2,1)(3,0)(3,-2) % becomes (-1,0)(-2,1)(-3,0)(-3,-2)
\closepath % line from (-3,-2) to (3,-2) CCW
```

[image]

## Question

In the combination, I want to get a result in which both outer and inner are properly drawn and the area bounded by both curves is filled with red. More precisely, the area enclosed by the inner curve must be transparent.

What causes the defect and how to solve it?

## MWE

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}

\psset
{
    fillstyle=solid,
    fillcolor=red,
    linewidth=5pt,
}


\def\Outer
{
    \psline(2,2)(3,4)(4,1)(4,-3)
    \reversepath % becomes (4,-3)(4,1)(3,4)(2,2)
    \scale{-1 1}
    \psline(2,2)(3,4)(4,1)(4,-3) % becomes (-2,2)(-3,4)(-4,1)(-4,-3)
    \closepath % line from (-4,-3) to (4,-3) CCW
}

\def\Inner
{
    \moveto(1,0)
    \psline(1,0)(2,1)(3,0)(3,-2)
    \reversepath % becomes (3,-2)(3,0)(2,1)(1,0)
    \scale{-1 1}
    \psline(1,0)(2,1)(3,0)(3,-2) % becomes (-1,0)(-2,1)(-3,0)(-3,-2)
    \closepath % line from (-3,-2) to (3,-2) CCW
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=t](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom{\Outer}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=t](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom{\Inner}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=t](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom
{
    \Outer  

    \scale{-1 1} % neutralize the previous scale

    \Inner
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

## Another scenario with `gradient eofill` plus `\reversepath`

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-grad}

\newpsstyle{gradient}
{
    gradbegin=red,
    gradend=yellow,
    gradangle=30,
    gradmidpoint=0.5,
}

\def\Outer{%
    \psline(2,2)(3,4)(4,1)(4,-3)
    \reversepath % becomes (4,-3)(4,1)(3,4)(2,2)
    \scale{-1 1}
    \psline(2,2)(3,4)(4,1)(4,-3) % becomes (-2,2)(-3,4)(-4,1)(-4,-3)
    \closepath % line from (-4,-3) to (4,-3) CCW
}
\def\Inner{%
    \psline[liftpen=2](1,0)(2,1)(3,0)(3,-1)
    \reversepath % becomes (3,-1)(3,0)(2,1)(1,0)
    \scale{-1 1}
    \psline(1,0)(2,1)(3,0)(3,-1) % becomes (-1,0)(-2,1)(-3,0)(-3,-1)
    \closepath % line from (-3,-1) to (3,-1) CCW
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=b](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom[fillstyle=gradient,fillcolor=red,linewidth=2mm]
{   
    \code{/clip /eoclip load def}
    \Outer
    \code{-1 1 scale} % to neutralize the previous scale
    \reversepath % to neutralize the next reversepath   
    \Inner
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Note

Assume that using `\reversepath` is mandatory. Removing it is a "crime". As I am also interested in TikZ, a solution in TikZ is also welcome as long as it conforms to the following requirements:

- reverse path technique must be used to construct a closed curve from a single side curve,
- the region bounded by the outer and inner closed curves can be filled with solid color, gradient color, patterns, and even clipped image.
- the region enclosed by the inner closed curve must be transparent (don't use  `opacity=0` please)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\def\Outer{%
    \psline(2,2)(3,4)(4,1)(4,-3)
    \reversepath % becomes (4,-3)(4,1)(3,4)(2,2)
    \scale{-1 1}
    \psline(2,2)(3,4)(4,1)(4,-3) % becomes (-2,2)(-3,4)(-4,1)(-4,-3)
    \closepath % line from (-4,-3) to (4,-3) CCW
}
\def\Inner{%
    \moveto(1,0)
    \psline(1,0)(2,1)(3,0)(3,-2)
    \reversepath % becomes (3,-2)(3,0)(2,1)(1,0)
    \scale{-1 1}
    \psline(1,0)(2,1)(3,0)(3,-2) % becomes (-1,0)(-2,1)(-3,0)(-3,-2)
    \closepath % line from (-3,-2) to (3,-2) CCW
}

\begin{document}
\psset{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,linewidth=5pt,}    
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=t](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \pscustom{\Outer}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=t](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \pscustom{\Inner}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=t](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!40]{%
        \gsave \Outer \fill[fillcolor=red] \stroke \grestore  
        \Inner
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or for an `eofill` which makes more sense here:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\def\OuterInner{%
    \psline(2,2)(3,4)(4,1)(4,-3)(-4,-3)(-4,1)(-3,4)(-2,2)(2,2)
    \moveto(2,1)
    \psline(1,0)(-1,0)(-2,1)(-3,0)(-3,-2)(3,-2)(3,0)
    \closepath
}
\begin{document}
\psset{linewidth=5pt}   
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=b](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=eofill,fillcolor=red]{\OuterInner}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=b](-5,-5)(5,5)   
\pscustom[fillstyle=eofill,fillcolor=red]{%
  \psline(0,0)(-1,0)(-2,1)(-3,0)(-3,-2)(0,-2)
  \moveto(0,-3)
  \psline(-4,-3)(-4,1)(-3,4)(-2,2)(0,2)
  \reversepath
  \scale{-1 1}
  \psline(0,0)(-1,0)(-2,1)(-3,0)(-3,-2)(0,-2)
  \moveto(0,-3)
  \psline(-4,-3)(-4,1)(-3,4)(-2,2)(0,2)}
\end{pspicture}
```

[image]

Comment: set `opacity=0.4` or whatever

Comment: ir does help. However, see edited answer