# How to make a custom closed curve independent from other closed curves in a single pscustom?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, asymptote, metapost

It is related to [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/404981/87876) but with a little bit different requirement. Rather than editing the previous one that potentially makes "inconvenience" to the accepted answer, let me ask it separately.

## Background

Bilateral closed curves can be constructed easily with `\reversepath`. For the sake of illustration, let's me take a simple example, i.e., drawing a helmet.

The following three macros define half part of head, eye and mouth curves of the helmet, respectively.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}

\def\HalfHead{\psline(-2,2)(-3,4)(-4,1)(-4,-5)}
\def\HalfEye{\psline(-1,0)(-2,1)(-3,0)(-3,-2)}
\def\HalfMouth{\psline(-2,-3)(-2,-4)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=b](-5,-5)(5,5)
\psset{linecolor=blue,arrows=->}
\HalfHead
\HalfEye
\HalfMouth
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The complete closed curves for head, eye and mouth can be obtained by enclosing each with a single `\pscustom` as follows.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}

\def\HalfHead{\psline(-2,2)(-3,4)(-4,1)(-4,-5)}
\def\HalfEye{\psline(-1,0)(-2,1)(-3,0)(-3,-2)}
\def\HalfMouth{\psline(-2,-3)(-2,-4)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=b](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom
{
    \HalfHead
    \reversepath
    \scale{-1 1}
    \HalfHead
    \closepath
}
\pscustom
{
    \HalfEye
    \reversepath
    \scale{-1 1}
    \HalfEye
    \closepath
}
\pscustom
{
    \HalfMouth
    \reversepath
    \scale{-1 1}
    \HalfMouth
    \closepath
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Among other purposes (such as filling with gradient color, filling with a pattern, or clipping another image), I want to fill the region bounded by the head, eye and mouth with a solid red.

Unfortunately `\pscustom` cannot be nested. I have to use a single `\pscustom` as follows but the result is disappointing.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}

\def\HalfHead{\psline(-2,2)(-3,4)(-4,1)(-4,-5)}
\def\HalfEye{\psline(-1,0)(-2,1)(-3,0)(-3,-2)}
\def\HalfMouth{\psline(-2,-3)(-2,-4)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=b](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom[fillstyle=eofill,fillcolor=red]
{
    \HalfHead
    \reversepath
    \scale{-1 1}
    \HalfHead
    \closepath

    \HalfEye
    \reversepath
    \scale{-1 1}
    \HalfEye
    \closepath

    \HalfMouth
    \reversepath
    \scale{-1 1}
    \HalfMouth
    \closepath
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[Herbert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2478/herbert)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405042/87876) in my previous question uses a trick that seems to be cumbersome. It forces us to retrace the path.

## Question

Recall that the built-in closed curves such as

- `psellipticwedge`
- `psellipse`
- `pscircle`
- `pswedge`
- `pspolygon`
- `psframe`
- `psccurve`

can be used independently in a single `\pscustom`,

[image]

I think it will be better if I make each of the closed curves for head, eye and mouth a single independent object.

How to make

```
\HalfHead
\reversepath
\scale{-1 1}
\HalfHead
\closepath
```

as a single independent object for the head such that it can be used together later in a single `pscustom`? A solution in Metapost, Asympotote, Tikz, etc is also welcome!

Comment: Are you looking for [inverse clip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/how-can-i-invert-a-clip-selection-within-tikz)?

Comment: @HenriMenke: Probably no. I am looking for reversed path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already gave you the answer in the other question!

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}

\def\HalfHead{\psline(0,-5)(-4,-5)(-4,1)(-3,4)(-2,2)(0,2)}
\def\HalfEye{\psline(0,-2)(-3,-2)(-3,0)(-2,1)(-1,0)(0,0)}
\def\HalfMouth{\psline(0,-4)(-2,-4)(-2,-3)(0,-3)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=b](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=eofill,fillcolor=red]{%
        \HalfHead
        \moveto(0,-2)
        \HalfEye
        \moveto(0,-4)
        \HalfMouth
        \reversepath
        \scale{-1 1}
        \HalfHead
        \moveto(0,-2)
        \HalfEye
        \moveto(0,-4)
        \HalfMouth
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\moveto` can be replaced by `liftpen=2`.

Comment: Is internally the same!

Answer (score 4):

This is `Asymptote` code to make a single object `gface`
from half parts of head, eye and mouth curves
using  `evenodd` `PostScript` fill rule in order 
to use it for filling and clipping:

```
// clcurve.asy
//
// run
// asy clcurve.asy
//
// to get clcurve.pdf
//    
settings.outformat="pdf";
import graph; size(9cm);
guide fpsline(... pair[] p){return graph(p);}

guide   HalfHead=fpsline((-2,2),(-3,4),(-4,1),(-4,-5));
guide   HalfEye=fpsline((-1,0),(-2,1),(-3,0),(-3,-2));
guide   HalfMouth=fpsline((-2,-3),(-2,-4));

guide[] g={HalfHead,HalfEye,HalfMouth};
guide[] gface;
for(var v:g) gface.push(v--reverse(scale(-1,1)*v)--cycle);
filldraw(gface,evenodd+orange,deepblue+0.8bp);

picture pic;

fill(pic,circle(0,100),lightyellow);
clip(pic,gface,evenodd);
add(shift(9,0)*pic);
```

[image]

Comment: It should be possible to apply this on PSTricks, I think.

Comment: @Artificial Stupidity:
It seems that there should be similar 
PostScript-level mechanism involved, so most probably, yes.